# Oracle job scheduler execution in daily one particular time, with two queries on that job task

Tags: sql, oracle, scheduled-tasks

I need help in Oracle job scheduler every day 1:00 pm.**I want execute two queries on that single job scheduler**. Queries like

first one is simple delete query .

```
delete from NEWS_NO_OF_VIEWS where TO_CHAR(MONTH_YEAR,'MM-YYYY') = 
                                                         TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM-YYYY')
```

and second one is insert query

```
INSERT INTO NEWS_NO_OF_VIEWS(NEWS_TYPE, NO_OF_VIEWS, MONTH_YEAR)    
((SELECT 'Latest News' AS NEWS_TYPE,NVL(SUM(NO_OF_VIEWED),0) NO_OF_VIEWS,MONTH_YEAR FROM(
    SELECT NO_OF_VIEWED,TO_CHAR(CREATED_DATE,'MM-YYYY') AS MONTH_YEAR FROM NEWS_LATEST_UR

 UNION ALL
    SELECT NO_OF_VIEWED,TO_CHAR(CREATED_DATE,'MM-YYYY')  AS MONTH_YEAR FROM NEWS_LATEST_EN
) E WHERE MONTH_YEAR = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM-YYYY') GROUP BY MONTH_YEAR)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What all you need to do is, create a procedure "give_some_proc_name" and put your "DELETE" and "INSERT" statement inside that procedure and commit as below, so that in future if you want to add or modify the statement it will be easy for you.

```
create or replace procedure give_some_proc_name
as
begin
delete from NEWS_NO_OF_VIEWS where TO_CHAR(MONTH_YEAR,'MM-YYYY') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM-YYYY');
INSERT INTO NEWS_NO_OF_VIEWS(NEWS_TYPE, NO_OF_VIEWS, MONTH_YEAR)    
((SELECT 'Latest News' AS NEWS_TYPE,NVL(SUM(NO_OF_VIEWED),0) NO_OF_VIEWS,MONTH_YEAR FROM(
    SELECT NO_OF_VIEWED,TO_CHAR(CREATED_DATE,'MM-YYYY') AS MONTH_YEAR FROM NEWS_LATEST_UR
 UNION ALL
    SELECT NO_OF_VIEWED,TO_CHAR(CREATED_DATE,'MM-YYYY')  AS MONTH_YEAR FROM NEWS_LATEST_EN
) E WHERE MONTH_YEAR = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM-YYYY') GROUP BY MONTH_YEAR);
commit;
end;
```

Then create the job as below which start at today 01:00 PM and runs every day at 01:00 PM. Inside job, your job_type will be "STORE_PROCEDURE" and job action will be "NAME_OF_PROCEDURE" i.e. "give_some_proc_name" with prefix schema name with "." separator as below.

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
    job_name        => 'give_some_name_to_job',
    job_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
    job_action      => 'schema_name.give_some_proc_name',
    start_date      => to_date(to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY')||' 13:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
    repeat_interval => 'freq=daily; byhour=13; byminute=0; bysecond=0;',
    enabled         => TRUE);
END;
```

Comment: let us know if you still facing any issue!